# Firebase storage list API listAll() is not calling onSuccess()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to read the pdf files in firebase storage. I am trying to use Google's latest API listAll() to list the files in a bucket.

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference listRef = storage.getReference();

listRef.listAll()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                        List<StorageReference> items = listResult.getItems();
```

On debugging, I could see 'listRef' is correctly getting my default bucket at firestore ("gs://myapp.appspot.com")

But it is not entering inside addonSuccessListener and jumps over it resulting in nulls. No error message is returned.

I am using Anonymous sign-in with Rules '2' version in storage rules.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please let me know where is the mistake?

Comment: Are you setting a breakpoint inside the callback?  listAll is asynchronous and returns immediately.  The callback is invoked some time later.

Comment: I tried to set the breakpoint in the function OnSuccess inside .addOnSuccessListener but the debugger is never reaching that point.

Comment: The API will either return a success or error.  You should check for both. Right now you are just showing a check for success.

Comment: Add on error listener and log the error

Comment: Yes. I have onFailure as well attached to it. The debugger doesn't enter even inside that as well.

Comment: Following Doug's first point above, I tried to set a button and attached on click to the function to call the code shown above. First time it gave nulls, but clicking the button second time gave results!! I tried this multiple times. Can anyone suggest a clue from this?